When does order 4 conjugate subgroups only intersect at {}?
Examples were given here of groups whose subgroups of order $4$ are conjugate, and intersect at the only normal subgroup of order $2$.
So I wonder if, for some group $G$:

there exists a subgroup of order $4$ whose conjugates in $G$ only intersect at $\{e\}$?
or even: there exist subgroups of order $4$ and for every such subgroup $H$, the conjugates of $H$ in $G$ only intersect at $\{e\}$?


Take $A_5$ as an example. It has five subgroups of order $4$:

$\{\mathrm{id},(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$
$\{\mathrm{id},(12)(35),(13)(25),(15)(23)\}$
$\{\mathrm{id},(12)(45),(14)(25),(15)(24)\}$
$\{\mathrm{id},(13)(45),(14)(35),(15)(34)\}$
$\{\mathrm{id}, (23)(45),(24)(35),(25)(34)\}$.

They are conjugate, and intersect only at $\{\mathrm{id}\}$.
Similarly, for every $n \ge 5$, the subgroups of $A_n$ of order $4$ are these five groups and their conjugates, and they intersect only at $\{\mathrm{id}\}$.
